# Does PHP have functions any() and all()?

Tags: php

```
// any() should return true if any of the element is true
$satisfied = any(array(x > 0, true, isset(y)));
```

I know how to create these functions myself, I'm just curious if they already exist in PHP.

Comment: When I can't remember if a particular language has a particular function, I use the language's docs. In this case, you might want to look at [the array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)

Comment: `pecl install functional` -- http://pecl.php.net/packages/functional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[in_array()](http://php.net/in_array)

Answer (score 2):

[Ouzo goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies) library contains Arrays::all and Arrays::any.

For example for array of users, assuming that class User has isCool method:

```
$isAnyCool = Arrays::any($users, Functions::extract()->isCool());
```

There are also other useful classes/functions for functional programming. Check out: 
http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/documentation/functional_programming.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://php.net/in_array.

```
<?php
$arraydef = array(x > 0, true, isset(y));
$satisfied = in_array(true, $arraydef);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

array_filter() can be used as a quite usable substitute of any()

I don't know one for the all() though (suppose it should return true in case all array elements are true)

Answer (score 0):

[Non-standard PHP library (NSPL)](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl) provides [all](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#allsequence-predicate) and [any](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#anysequence-predicate) as well as many other useful functions.